# I want to change the JOptionPane showInputDialog title text font, font size, color and input field text size using UIManager

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I want to change the JOptionPane showInputDialog title text font, font size, color and input field text
size using UIManager

```
UIManager UI=new UIManager();
UI.put("OptionPane.messageFont", new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
UI.put("OptionPane.titleText", fontss);
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Quantity :","productName",-1)
```

Comment: I believe the defaults keys you want are `OptionPane.font` and `OptionPane.foreground`.  The text field is just a JTextField, so if you want to use UIManager to change it, you’ll need to change the font for all JTextFields;  the defaults key for that is `TextField.font`.  By the way, UIManager.put is a static method, so you should remove your first line for code.  Creating a UIManager accomplishes nothing.